# log4j2 логирование команд отправляемых в консоль

Tags: java

Мне нужно логировать в файл, не только вывод консоли, но и команды, которые бали посланы в консоль, и сделать это мне нужно через `xml` конфиг `log4j2`, если это конечно возможно.

log4j2.xml - https://pastebin.com/5UvhMNJ0

На данный момент, логируется так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вы попробовали и у вас не получилось?

Comment: michael_best, конкретно с этим, я почти не какой информаций не нашел, а что нашел, не понял вообще. : (

Comment: принимайте в структуру данных команды, которые вы присылаете.

Comment: а потом логиньте их?

Comment: Не очень понял Вас, пример можно?